# How to set up a notification for "New in repository" packages?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, repository

I want to see a list of "New in repository" packages every time they appear after cache update. How can I achieve this?

#### Related questions:

[How exactly does Synaptic keep track of "New in repository" packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/253774/20275)

[Is there an RSS feed that alerts subscribers of new/updated packages in the official repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56370/20275)

Comment: why not use Synaptic manager for the purpose :)

Comment: New as in updated? Brand new?

Comment: I usually use `apt-get update` and I currenly see them only in Synaptic. But I want an automatic notification, not to check them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just asking a wrong question.
All I need is these RSS feeds:

[Is there an RSS feed that alerts subscribers of new/updated packages in the official repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56370/is-there-an-rss-feed-that-alerts-subscribers-of-new-updated-packages-in-the-offi)

Answer (score 3):

[Set up an MTA on your system](https://askubuntu.com/q/7993/7808) if you haven't already, so that emails sent from the command line will work.

Install the `bsd-mailx` package to give you a standard command `mail` to send emails to the MTA from the command line.

Write a script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p ~/new-package-detector
cd ~/new-package-detector
apt-cache search .|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq > new-package-list
if [ -f old-package-list ]; then
    comm -23 new-package-list old-package-list > new-in-repository
    if [ -s new-in-repository ]; then
        mail -s 'New packages available' int_ua@example.com < new-in-repository
    fi
fi
mv new-package-list old-package-list
```

Then [set up a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/7808) to run your script regularly. You might need to add an `apt-get update` to the start of the script, too, in order to make sure that it happens before the check.

Comment: Isn't that info part of package info in cache? Does synaptic have its' own cache?

Comment: I'm fairly sure (but not certain) that synaptic uses the system cache. But if you will rely on automation, then you won't always run synaptic directly, right?

Comment: The point is I don't want to have another package cache **if** that info is already a part of apt/dpkg system.

Comment: You won't. My script uses the system cache. The apt/dpkg system does not track "new" packages as such, just the archive package lists. So `old-package-list` has to be kept. But that file is not exactly big or any kind of burden, surely?

Comment: creating a new file is not using a system cache. I consider it big as long as it's duplicating the info. But I'm still not sure if it is. That's another question, I'll add a link soon :) I've found the RSS. I'll award bounty to you, I appreciate your help, but I'll add my own answer to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think synaptic package manager already shows this information.

Comment: yes, but I don't run it very often. And it does not notify, just passively has them under one section.

Comment: @int_ua yes :) This is now solved.