# How exactly does Synaptic keep track of "New in repository" packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, aptitude

Is this info part of APT cache or does it create a separate file to compare with new cache?
Where is it stored then?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the files you are looking for are:

- /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
- /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin

This is a local package database for binary and source packages respectively. It is updated every time you run `apt-get update` or programs like Synaptic do that somehow.

Comment: yes, but it **is** the APT cache, is that info stored there? In case it is how can we extract it?

Comment: @int_ua, didn't understand you from the very beginning. Yes, sure - /var/cache/* is part of APT cache :) I doubt that you can find the answer to your question even in documentation. To be sure whether Synaptic uses this file or not you'll probably have to have a look in the code. People out there on the Internet say it does (well, I also don't see any reason why it wouldn't - however this is just an assumption). As of how to parse it. It is a binary file, so also only programmatically. I'd have a look at some APT libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the information from the apt cache, you use `apt-cache` or other Debian/Ubuntu tools such as aptitude. For instructions and examples, see `man apt-cache` or the [Debian Package Management manuals](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_literal_apt_get_literal_literal_apt_cache_literal_vs_literal_aptitude_literal)

For example:

```
apt-cache show software-center
```

will list the complete package information.

Synaptic is essentially a GUI wrapper around apt, so its apt that is keeping track of the repository and package information and Synaptic is querying it.

apt-cache wrapped in bash scripts is probably the easiest way to do something similar on your own. Synaptic uses libapt-pkg* via C++, but there are also libraries for Perl and Python.

**Finding new packages in aptitude**

```
aptitude search '~N'
```

Comment: Does APT cache track "New in repository" info? Check the question, please.

Comment: Yes, it's all in the Debian manuals. You can use apt-cache or aptitude to find and track new packages. apt uses an xapian database that the other tools search.

Comment: the bounty ended, but if you'll add **how** to get it with `apt-cache` or any other **precise** answer I'll award you 100 points.

Comment: Ok, I'm still looking into some details and may edit the answer some more, but I added the specific command for aptitude. If you still need something else specific, please let me know.

Comment: But the questions is how does aptitude keep track of these packages. I assume it uses the same method as Synaptic. But I can't find it myself yet.

Comment: I know, that's the part I'm still working on. I'll add more as I come up with it.